# Zend Framework & PHPunit path issues?

Tags: php, zend-framework, path, phpunit, extend

When I extend a ZF class, I get path errors. Here is my test:

```
<?php
require_once ('Zend/Acl.php'); // gives error w/o
require_once ('../application/models/Acl.php');

class Model_AclTest extends ControllerTestCase
{

    /**
        * @var Model_Acl
        */
    protected $acl;

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->acl = new Model_Acl(2, 'sims');
    }

    public function testHasUsername()
    {
        echo $this->acl->username;
        $this->assert($this->acl->username);
    }
}
```

Here is the Model_Acl class:

```
class Model_Acl extends Zend_Acl
{
    private $username;
    private $userid;
    private $userroles;
    private $allroles;

    public function __construct($userid, $username)
    {
        if (method_exists(parent, '__construct')) parent::__construct();
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->userid = $userid;
        $this->setRoles();
        $this->setResources();
        $this->setPrivilages();
        return $this;
    }
...
}
```

I get this error, unless I require 'Zend/Acl.php'.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Zend_Acl' not found in /mnt/dev/mragent/application/models/Acl.php on line 6
```

So I figure maybe something is not quite up to snuff yet, and continue with this slight inconvenience. Then I get the following error from phpunit itself:

```
1) Model_AclTest::testHasUsername
Use of undefined constant parent - assumed 'parent'

/mnt/dev/mragent/application/models/Acl.php:14
/mnt/dev/mragent/tests/application/models/AclTest.php:18
```

So something is really wrong I think. Or I'm doing something really wrong.

How do I set up my path(s) correctly?

Comment: I think that one possible reason could be that you ControllerTestCase that should be used for testing controllers. In your case you want to test models. So you should use/create ModelTestCase that extends Zend_Test_PHPUnit_DatabaseTestCase as a parent class for testing your models.

Comment: I'll have to look into this. Though, my model does not necessarily access the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just posting this so others will find the answer:

I had to upgrade to PHPunit 3.4. PHPunit 3.2 ignores the bootstrap file specified in the xml file. Perhaps this feature was not implemented at the time. After that, *everything* works as expected and I do not need to require *any* files from my project or the php path after the Zend_Application has been bootstrapped.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you'll want to look at this the following line:

```
class Model_Acl extends Zend_Acl
```

This is the reason that you need the following:

```
require_once ('Zend/Acl.php'); // gives error w/o
```

In order to get things working without adding the above line, you'll need to setup your include paths so the autoloader can find the Acl.php file which is directly under the 'Zend' directory. You include path simply needs to include the directory which is the parent of the 'Zend' directory. Generally this will be your "library" directory.

As for the "parent" issue:

```
Use of undefined constant parent - assumed 'parent'
```

You are seeing this because you have the following code:

```
if (method_exists(parent, '__construct')) parent::__construct();
```

Which should actually be:

```
if (method_exists(get_parent_class($this), '__construct')) parent::__construct();
```

You could alternatively write the following:

```
method_exists(get_parent_class($this), '__construct') && parent::__construct();
```

This is ever so slightly more concise (as much as one can get with PHP) and a little bit less noise.

The reason for this?

The very first thing on the line (far left) is "method_exists" which is a quick indicator that this is what we care about. The very end of the line (far left, besides the semicolon), is the end result. Also, the && generally is a good indicator that there should only ever be one statement following it. If that changes, it is easy to see that the entire statement likely needs to be re-factored rather than attaching another statement after parent::__construct();

EDIT: further information regarding autoloading:

create a autoload.php.dist file in your project root (replace '/PATH/TO/YOUR/PHP5/LIB/DIR'):

```
<?php /* autoload.php.dist */

$includePaths = array( realpath('/PATH/TO/YOUR/PHP5/LIB/DIR'), get_include_path());
set_include_path( join(\PATH_SEPARATOR, $includePaths) );

spl_autoload_register(function($className) {
    $className = ltrim($className, '\\');
    $fileName  = '';
    $namespace = '';
    if ($lastNsPos = strripos($className, '\\')) {
        $namespace = substr($className, 0, $lastNsPos);
        $className = substr($className, $lastNsPos + 1);
        $fileName  = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $namespace) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    }
    $fileName .= str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className) . '.php';
    require $fileName;
}, true, true);
```

Create a bootstrap that can be re-used (bootstrap.php)

```
<?php /* bootstrap.php */
if (file_exists($file = __DIR__.'/autoload.php')) {
    require_once $file;
} elseif (file_exists($file = __DIR__.'/autoload.php.dist')) {
    require_once $file;
}
```

Create a phpunit.xml.dist file which utilizes your bootstrap.php (replace './your/test/directory/here'):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- phpunit.xml.dist -->
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         colors="false"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false"
         syntaxCheck="false"
         bootstrap="./bootstrap.php"
>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Test Suite">
            <directory>./your/test/directory/here</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Now you can run phpunit from your root project directory.

Comment: Hi Wil, thanks for the reply. It looks like 'get_parent_class($this)' rather than just 'parent' is the ticket for that problem. I'll try it as soon as I'm back. However, the path issue is still troubling. I keep ZF in /usr/share/php5 and that is in the php include path. The app runs fine. Oddly, I have a cron job execute a PHP script which bootstraps the app and does some maintenance tasks. Various models from the app are used w/o special care to be 'required'. This works fine as well. So I can't figure that out.

Comment: As mentioned by David in his response, you will need to setup autoloading. You mentioned that you have CLI scripts running with a bootstrap. You'll need to bootstrap PHPUnit as well. In your phpunit.xml file you can specify the path to your bootstrap file. I generally create one boostrap file that is shared between the CLI apps, web app, and PHPUnit. This file basically just calls my autoloader and that's it. I'll update my original answer to include further direction on this.

Comment: Which is basically what I am doing. Except, I'm not explicitly creating an autoloader because Zend_Application creates one for me.

Comment: Zend_Application will utilize your autoloadernamespaces. You can specify them like autoloadernamespaces[] = ... or autoloadernamespaces.key = ...

Answer (score 1):

You must use an autoloader to turn the class name Zend_Acl into the file path Zend/Acl.php. This should go in your PHPUnit bootstrap.php file. Zend Framework supplies an easy-to-use autoloader.

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
$loader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
```

The Zend and ZendX "namespaces" are automatically registered. If you want to register your own "namespace," use this:

```
$loader->registerNamespace('MyNamespace_');
```

You can of course use your own autoload function if you like, but since you're already using Zend Framework it seems like a good route.

BTW, the quotes around "namespace" are to denote that these are not true PHP namespaces but rather class naming conventions that turn the parts between underscores into directory names.

Comment: Why, if my I already include an autoloader, do I have to include one again? Doesn't Zend_Application already set up an auto loader for me?

Comment: @sims - I don't know if `Zend_Application` will set up the autoloader automatically. It seems unlikely since it's not doing it. Can you post your `bootstrap.php`?

Comment: It's working fine now. It was a stupid problem. Basically, I was following docs WRT PHPunit's XML file. However, an older version (3.2) of PHPunit did not read all the options in the XML file - including the "bootstrap". So my Zend_Application instance was not even created, leaving me with no autoloader - not nothing. 3.4 works well. Thanks for your help!